# Is it possible to drag & drop one ImageView onto another to create a new one?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I know the question seems a bit vague, but I am creating an "alchemy" game whereby users drag different earthly elements onto one another to see what the combination produces.

At the moment, I can drag views around the screen, but I want them to be able to interact with each other. For example, when the user drags one ImageView onto another it will produce a new one, either programmatically or in some snazzy way...

I am just wondering what the best approach to this may be?

Here's my code so far, I've removed all the crap I had to show the barebones:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView earthImg;
private ImageView waterImg;
private ViewGroup rootLayout;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
    earthImg = rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.earthView);
    waterImg = rootLayout.findViewById(R.id.waterView);
    earthImg.setOnTouchListener(new UserTouchListener());
    waterImg.setOnTouchListener(new UserTouchListener());
}

private final class UserTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    float dX, dY;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                view.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;

    }
}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.alchgame.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/earthView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/earth_element"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/waterView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/earthView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/earthView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/earthView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/water_element" />
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

I added the view above for reference

Answer (score 0):

You could add `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to your switch statement, then calculate the bounds of the view you dragged based on the x and y co-ordinates (which you can get based on your dragging code) and the size of the view. Check if these numbers match the numbers of another view. If they do, you can then do whatever you need, like make a new image, delete the old ones, animate the dragged one back to where it started etc.

Additionally, views have `getTop()`, `getLeft()`... etc methods that will return that edge based on the parent.

So you could do something like:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    //view = view being dragged
    String dTag = view.getTag();
    for (View mView: myImageViews){
        if (!mView.getTag().equals(dTag){                
               if (view.getTop() <= mView.getBottom() && view.getBottom() >= mView.getBottom()){
               if (view.getLeft() <= mView.getRight() && view.getRight() >= mView.getRight()){
                    //match
                }
                else if (view.getRight() >= mView.getLeft() && view.getLeft() <= mView.getLeft()){
                    //match
                }
                //No match
            }
            else if (view.getBottom() >= mView.getTop() && view.getTop() <= mView.getTop()){
                if (view.getLeft() <= mView.getRight()  && view.getRight() >= mView.getRight()){
                    //match
                }
                else if (view.getRight() >= mView.getLeft() && view.getLeft() <= mView.getLeft()){
                    //match
                }
                //No match
            }
        }
    }
    break;
```

I'm not sure if there is some 'snazzy' way to do this in vanilla Android, but I'm sure there's probably some sort of library for exactly this, or you could do it manually as mentioned above.

Hopefully this has helped.

EDIT:
I'm assuming here that you will make an arraylist of your image views or similar. I would also like to point out that you will need to check if the current view in the loop is the one you are dragging, if it is, you should just move on to the next one. You could achieve this by adding a tag to each view and then checking if the tag matches the tag of the dragged view. I'll update the code above.

Comment: Ha, I actually just made an ArrayList but i didn't think of a tag - so thank you again!

Comment: You should be fine to access them as long as you declare the ArrayList as `final`.

Comment: Cheers again. However, I'm struggling to get the current view which is being dragged...

Comment: My code is just an example; the view being dragged in your code would just be `view` since that's the view this touch event was called on and you can see that by the fact that you called `view.animate()` so I'll change the variables in my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Extend View.OnDragListener and set it to a container of each "element"

```
class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(...);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(...);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        View element = (View) event.getLocalState();
        View elementContainer = (View) element.getParent();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                element.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackground(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign Entry to Day
                View newContainer = v;
                doSnazzyStuff(element, newContainer);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
                element.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void doSnazzyStuff(View element, View newContainer) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and set something like this on each "element" to affect how it looks when it's dragged.

```
private final class ElementClickListener implements OnLongClickListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you create/extend custom views for your "element" and containers then you can do some pretty powerful stuff.